# Content update for all visitors through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm looking for a solution to fix the following problem:
When I hold down my mousebutton, some DIV will change it's background-color from red to green and when is lift up from the button the color will change back to red again.

Now it works perfectly well in my own browser (my client side).. But what I'm trying to do is that when I down the button in my browser, the DIV should change it's color on my screen aswell as on the screen of my neighbour or any other visitor.

Can I manage to do this with JS/AJAX? Or do I need some other server side scripting language like PhP to make this onmousedown/up happen for all visitors if 1 person clicks?

Comment: Are you talking about select color, as in when you hold down your button and select the text or just by clicking the div? Also, showing us the code for that div would be nice

Comment: As in clicking a DIV and changing the color from another DIV realtime, the only code I have right now is JS and so client side. I need a solution that works realtime, which is probably going to be server side as mentioned by plalx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the DIV should change it's color on my screen aswell as on the screen
>   of my neighbour or any other visitor

You will absolutely need server-side support to build such a realtime application. If you have the choice of the server-side technology, I would recommend looking into [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Also, you will want to learn about [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebSockets).

EDIT:

> You could also use a service like [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/), they host the centralized
>   messaging and distribution part of this and have JavaScript libraries
>   to make something like this very easy. – @Jason Sperske

Comment: With these two I will be able to change DOM elements real time?

Comment: @VoogdWD Well basically the server will act as a mediator between every client. The clients will notify the server when an action is performed, such as pushing down the mouse button. The server will then broadcast that information to other clients wich will react accordingly. Have a look at some WebSockets tutorials and you should be good to go ;)

Comment: I've just read the pages about node.js and websockets. In combination with your description this will probably do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use a service like [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/), they host the centralized messaging and distribution part of this and have JavaScript libraries to make something like this very easy.